# Add title text to legend block in octave

Tags: plot, octave, legend-properties

I'm trying to add a title to the legend block in a plot I've got in Octave ([like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vR9MR.png)). I've had a dig through the properties that are available on the plot and have found the 'title' attribute, but when I set it there's no change on the plot.

Here's an example of what I'm trying:

```
a=linspace(0, 2*pi())
h=plot(sin(a))  
hleg = legend("Data 1")
set(hleg, 'title', 'Data Series')
```

I've also tried this:

```
hlegtitle = get(hleg, 'title') 
get(hlegtitle, 'string')
```

which returns `Data Series`, so I'm clearly setting the property, but the title does not appear on the legend.

Is there something else that needs to be set somewhere -- is the title block being drawn off-screen, or is there a boolean or something that causes it to be hidden I've compared the various properties on `hlegtitle` with those for other components of the plot, and they all seem the same.

Is there something that I'm missing, or is this just not possible?

Comment: Your code runs fine on Octave >=4.0 with qt and fltk toolkits but not with gnuplot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code runs fine under the current development version,
which uses `graphics_toolkit("qt")` by default.
[image: current dev version, graphics_tooolkit("qt")]

With the same dev version, but `graphics_toolkit("gnuplot")`,
the legend title is missing:
[image: current dev version, graphics_tooolkit("gnuplot")]

It is not just "off-screen" because reducing the `gca` height
does not display the title.

It is still possible to set the title "by hand", with [`text`](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/text.html):

```
graphics_toolkit("gnuplot")
a = linspace(0, 2 * pi, 101);
h = plot(a, sin(a));
hleg = legend("Data 1")

set(hleg, "title", "Data Series")
# This is changing the gca "position"
legend("location", "northeastoutside")

# Now tweak the gca height, to provide room above the legend
gca_pos = get(gca, "position");
gca_pos(4) *= 0.9;
# The plot width has to be tweaked by hand,
# because the legend position is not reliable
gca_pos(3) = 0.66;
set(gca, "position", gca_pos)

# set text
leg_pos = get(hleg, "position")
x_pos = 1.2;
y_pos = 1.05;
leg_title = "title";
text(x_pos, y_pos, leg_title, 
     "units", "normalized",
     "fontName", get(gcf, "DefaultAxesFontName"),
     "fontSize", get(gcf, "DefaultAxesFontSize"))
```

which yields
[image: title set "by hand"]

Comment: Thanks. I've been using gnuplot because it yields better looking plots for my purposes downstream; it looks like this is a shortcoming of that method.